# Writing in acceptable values into if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, logic

I'm having a little trouble getting this to work, trying to evaluate two values and result in a rule violation but accept N/A as the only acceptable value outside of the values equaling.

here is what i have so far.

```
x = value1
y = value2  

if x == "N/A" or x == y: 
    Rule.Violated = False
else:
    Rule.Violated = True
```

Rule.Violated is a built in function in the system I'm using to return an error message one true and not returning one if the rule violation is false, i dont think the result of the if statement matters to figuring out the logic though, but if you need more info let me know.

Comment: So what exactly is failing? It's accepting more values then it should, less values?

Comment: You should use `raise` to raise an error/exception rather than setting some global variable to True... Also, if `Rule.Violated` is a function, shouldn't you call it (rather than overwriting its value)?

Comment: sorry i used the wrong word, not a function. i honestly dont even have access to tell you what rule.violated really is, i just know it raises an error in our system when its violated. sorry, wish i had more info.  its failing because it will not accept N/A as a valid value to make the rule not violate.

Comment: whats with the downvote? explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, thanks to those who helped.  My problem was with data types, ill be sure to mention the data types next time i have a question, but for those who are curious, here is the answer.

had to use a function told to me by the developer to get the field as a string and     compare the strings.  Previously was trying to compare date time to a string, bonehead move on my part. FormSet is also a built in reference in our system that i was trying to avoid having to use anything other than straight python to ask the question.

```
x = FormSet.GetFieldString(CurrentForm, “SUM_VALUE_DATE”)
y = FormSet.GetFieldString(CurrentForm, “ORG_APPRAISAL_DATE”)

if x == “N/A” or FormSet.GetDaySpan(x, y) == 0:
            Rule.Violated = False
else:
            Rule.Violated = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd likely do something like this:

```
if x not in ('N/A', y,):
    raise ValueError('my message')
```

Using exception handling is the recommended, Pythonic way of deailing with input validation.

(Also, using the built-in exception types are recommended as chances are if the exception types provided cover the *entire* stdlib, you won't need to create new ones)

Comment: this help, i tried it as you wrote it but the system im in threw and error, i have to stick to using rule.violated.  but thank you for the help.  this unfortunately didnt work either. i tried by replacing your line raise ValueError('my message') with rule.violated = true else: rule.violated = false

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
Rule.Violated = (x != y and x != "N/A")
```

Comment: Isn't this just a rearrangement of OP's current (failing) code? (Why would this work if OP's code fails?)

Comment: nope, this didnt work, thanks though